# Sharepoint 2007 to Sharepoint 2010 Migration Issues

Tags: feature, migration, upgrade, site-definition, database-attach

I recently migrated SharePoint 2007 portal to SharePoint 2010 using content database attach/detach method. After mounting the database in SharePoint 2010, site collection got created. When I browse the site I getting error as “Server error: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=177673”.
Also, I did a test-spcontentdatabase check and got many errors MissingSiteDefinition, MissingFeature etc. Any idea how to resolve this error. Shall I upgrade SharePoint to Service Pack 2. I am struggling with it . Please advise if anyone has faced same issue before.

Comment: We really need more info to be able to help you. MissingSiteDefinition and MissingFeature would suggest you need to re-install solutions from your MOSS site, but without a list of errors from migration error log we probably can only guess on what the issue is

Answer (score 4):

Are you missing custom solutions in your new 2010 farm, that exist in the 2007 farm? Compare the installed features/solutions in both farms.

However, you really should upgrade to SP2. The preupgradecheck stsadm command was added in SP2 and is very good at identifying where you're going to have issues. The upgrade alone may even solve your problems.